# Println with unresolved strings

Tags: java, string, variables, println

I am running into a problem when I try to println my strings. I want the entire println to read something like this "BAR, ORANGE, and PLUM". The strings don't seem to be communicating with the println statement. I am very new to java and I am extremely lost so please explain your suggestions very basically. I would really appreciate not only an answer, but also an explanation, that way I don't make this mistake again. Thank you for your time.

```
/*
 * This program will simulate playing a slot machine.
 * It will provide instructions to the user with an initial stake of $50 and then let the user play until either the money runs out or the player quits.
 * Author: Zac Saunders
 * Version: 1.3
 */


import acm.program.*;

import java.awt.*;

import acm.util.RandomGenerator;

public class SlotMachine_V2 extends GraphicsProgram {

    RandomGenerator rgen = new RandomGenerator();

    public void run(){

        waitForClick();
        rollWheels();
    }

    public void rollWheels(){

        Wheel_1();
        Wheel_2();
        Wheel_3();
        println("You rolled:"+aa, + bb, +cc"");
        run();

    }

    public void Wheel_1(){

        int a = rgen.nextInt(1, 6);

        if( a == 1){//BAR//

            String aa =(" BAR, ");

        }else if( a == 2){//BELL//

            String aa =(" BELL, ");

        }else if( a == 3){//PLUM//

            String aa =(" PLUM, "); 

        }else if( a == 4){//ORANGE//

            String aa =(" ORANGE, ");

        }else if( a == 5){//CHERRY//

            String aa =(" CHERRY, ");       

        }else if( a == 6){//DASH (-)//

            String aa =(" -, ");        
        }
    }

    public void Wheel_2(){

        int b = rgen.nextInt(1, 6);

        if( b == 1){//BAR//

            String bb =("BAR, ");

        }else if( b == 2){//BELL//

            String bb =("BELL, ");

        }else if( b == 3){//PLUM//

            String bb =("PLUM, ");  

        }else if( b == 4){//ORANGE//

            String bb =("ORANGE, ");

        }else if( b == 5){//CHERRY//

            String bb =("CHERRY, ");        

        }else if( b == 6){//DASH (-)//

            String bb =("-, ");     
        }

    }

    public void Wheel_3(){

        int c = rgen.nextInt(1, 6);

        if( c == 1){//BAR//

            String cc =("and BAR");

        }else if( c == 2){//BELL//

            String cc =("and BELL");

        }else if( c == 3){//PLUM//

            String cc =("and PLUM");    

        }else if( c == 4){//ORANGE//

            String cc =("and ORANGE");

        }else if( c == 5){//CHERRY//

            String cc =("and CHERRY");      

        }else if( c == 6){//DASH (-)//

            String cc =("and -");       
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't start putting parentheses around your `String`s. Please.

Comment: Why are you declaring the same string over and over?

Comment: That way whatever the random Generator sets decides the wheel is, that String becomes aa or bb or cc. IS there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare your variables on the class. The way you do it now, you declare new variables in the methods and they are in scope only in those methods.

```
public class SlotMachine_V2 extends GraphicsProgram {

    String aa;
    String bb;
    String cc;

    ...

}
```

Then you use them:

```
public void Wheel_1(){

    int a = rgen.nextInt(1, 6);

    if( a == 1){//BAR//

        aa = " BAR, ";

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you!   That seems to fix the println, but in the the Wheel 1/2/3 methods, the  "value of the local variable aa/bb/cc is not used."

Comment: You don't need the local variables. Remove them.

Comment: If I remove them, how will the println get the aa,bb, and cc values? I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, like I said I am new at this.

Comment: Yes, all instance variables (fields) declared on the class level are visible for all non-static methods of this class.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, you just made my night.

Comment: Maybe you can help. How do I reference the results from what is printed? Ex. If(println = BAR, -, and PLUM){...

Comment: Create a local variable `String x = aa + bb + cc;` You can use it to compare but use `x.equals("...")` and not `==`.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring `String aa =(" BAR, ");`  within code blocks so the visibility is limited to the code blocks.

try moving `String aa` to the class level i.e. just below `RandomGenerator rgen = new RandomGenerator();` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
System.out.println(String.format("%s, %s, and %s",aa,bb,cc));
```

and don't put any commas around aa,bb,cc

Comment: Thank you! Now, what is the difference between doing this and what Szymon suggested?

Comment: you need not to track commas and string format is std process to format strings batter then concatenation as it increases the readability of code

Comment: I have one more question for you, how do I reference the results from what is printed? Ex. If(println = BAR, -, and PLUM){...